# Is there any Android shell command to know the connected device name

Tags: shell

When i connect my phone to my system and when i enter "**adb devices**" it shows

```
"List of devices attached
09478d300f4133f6        device"
```

Is there a shell command to extract only the name of device? I just want "09478d300f4133f6".

As i am not a programmer i am not expecting any code. Great if the solution can be provided with any shell commands.

Comment: You can use "grep" and "sed" to strip unwanted stuff out, but you will need to define behavior for the cases where there are no devices or multiple devices.  (If there aren't multiple devices, then programmatic access to the serial number isn't all that useful...?)

Comment: [maybe look here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=adb+get+connected+device+name) and to anyone wanting to close, it could be on topic on SU but it's not off-topic here since it is a tool commonly used by programmers whether the OP is using it for that or not

Comment: You should mention which os you're running.

Comment: I have mixed feeling on the presence or absence of the [android] tag, as the output of `adb devices` is Android-specific. You can answer the question exactly as stated without Android knowledge, but without knowing the possible format of the device serial (e.g. can it contain spaces) and the possible varieties of output (e.g. what appears when multiple devices are connected), it's not easy to give a complete answer. OTOH, the question is a bit lacking, as it asks how to accomplish a very specific thing, when it should probably be asking for a solution to the actual problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Linux or Mac OS to run this:

```
adb devices | grep -w "device" | awk '{print $1;}'
```

Comment: Or any shell environment on windows such as cygwin or git bash.